# web config http to https redirect exception

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I have two domains hosted at GoDaddy:

www.mymaindomain.com

www.mysecondarydomain.com

The main domain is stored in a root ftp folder, the secondary domain is stored in a separate folder "second".
I've purchased SSL certificate for my main domain, and applied http to https redirect in web.config, as described in GoDaddy help:

```html
<configuration> 
 <system.webServer> 
  <rewrite> 
   <rules> 
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
     <match url="(.*)"></match> 
     <conditions> 
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"></add> 

     </conditions> 
     <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"></action> 
    </rule> 
    </rules> 
  </rewrite> 
 </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

The problem is that the traffic to the secondary domain is also redirected to https and users receive security alerts.
I've tried to add exceptions for the secondary domain as following:

```html
<add input="{R:1}" pattern="second" negate="true"></add>
```

I also tried:

```html
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.\/?=_\-\&%:]*[s][e][c][o][n][d][a-zA-Z0-9.\/?=_\-\&%]*" ignoreCase="true"></add>
```

Non of them worked.

After spending whole day, I've failed to figure out how to exclude the secondary domain from http to https redirect rule.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

change the folder for `mymaindomain` to be a folder within your ftp root folder and sibling to the folder `mysecondarydomain`

Comment: Thanks Jeff, unfortunately it is not possible in GoDaddy hosting. 'mymaindomain' must be in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue with the following line of code:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mysecondarydomain\.com" negate="true" ignoreCase="true"></add>
```